# How to solve a nonlinear coupled PDE with initial and some boundary values

Tags: finite-element-method, differential-equations

I would like to solve the following nonlinear coupled PDE with a mix of initial conditions and boundary values:

```
rMax = 0.01;
sol = First@NDSolve[{
Derivative[2, 0][g][r, z] + Derivative[0, 2][g][r, z] == u[r, z]^2,
Derivative[2, 0][u][r, z] + Derivative[0, 1][u][r, z] == -g[r, z],
Derivative[1, 0][u][0, z] == 0.0,
Derivative[1, 0][u][rMax, z] == 0.0,
u[rMax, z] == 0.0,
u[r, 0] == g[r, 0] == Sin[\[Pi] r/rMax],
Derivative[1, 0][g][0, z] == g[rMax, z] == 0.0},
{u, g}, {r, 0, rMax}, {z, 0, 0.01}]
```

but I receive the following error message (in version 10.0.1.0):

`NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve`.

The offender is the square term `u[r, z]^2` in the first equation; without the square NSolve[] executes without errors. NDSolve seems to apply the FEM method by default to such problems. I'm wondering why NDSolve[] doesn't switch back to another (propagation-type) algorithm? When I add the option `Method -> "MethodOfLines"`, the error message changes to

`NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.`

and I don't quite understand why this is because my time-like variable is `z` and I'm setting initial conditions only for `z=0` and then boundary conditions at `r=0` and `r=rMax` which should be OK?

Any ideas how to solve my problem? Another post suggested calling low-level FEM routines directly, is this a solution? What's the advantage of using FEM on an initial condition/boundary value problem over other methods: speed, accuracy, robustness?

Comment: Try `NDSolve[..., Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> z}]` -- You'll get another error message, but perhaps that will give you a clue.

Comment: OK, the new error message is `NDSolve::tvic: "z cannot be used as the temporal independent variable because the conditions {u[r,0]==Sin[6283.19\ r],g[r,0]==Sin[6283.19\ r]} for that dimension do not constitute sufficient initial conditions given at only one value of z."` Why would the condition at z=0 not be sufficient, being at the beginning of the requested solution range?

Comment: Perhaps a time derivative needs to be specified at `z == 0`?

Comment: I may be wrong but won't your `Derivative[1, 0][u][0, z] == 0` condition be inconsistent with `u[r, 0] == Sin[π r/rMax]`?

Comment: @Silvia: Yes, you're correct, so let's replace the sine term by Cos[Pi/2 r/rMax].

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks for the comment. I managed to get NDSolve[] to run after adding the initial condition `Derivative[0, 1][g][r, 0] == 0.0` and `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> z}` as you suggested. The solution is terribly slow, though, and I feel this shouldn't be the case since there's no fast variation or stiffness/singularity in the physical system I'm trying to model. I added the options `AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, MaxSteps -> 10^5`. Do you think it's worth playing with the discretization method, specify a grid size etc.?

Comment: Could you edit your Q to show the updated code you're using?  If I replace the sine by `Cos[Pi/2 r/rMax]`, I still get inconsistent boundary and initial conditions (for `Derivative[1, 0][u][rMax, z] == 0`).

Answer (score 5):

In version 12.0 you can solve this:

```
rMax = 0.01;
{usol, gsol} = NDSolveValue[{
   Derivative[2, 0][g][r, z] + Derivative[0, 2][g][r, z] == 
    u[r, z]^2,
   Derivative[2, 0][u][r, z] + Derivative[0, 1][u][r, z] == -g[r, z],
   u[rMax, z] == 0.0, u[r, 0] == g[r, 0] == Sin[\[Pi] r/rMax], 
   g[rMax, z] == 0.0}, {u, g}, {r, 0, rMax}, {z, 0, 0.01}]
```

I have removed the Neumann zero BCs.

Plot the solution for g:

```
Plot3D[gsol[r, z], {r, 0, rMax}, {z, 0, 0.01}]
```

[image]