# FEM giving " ... is not a polynomial error"

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, finite-element-method

Executing the program below I get the

> ... is not a polynomial

error message. I don't have an idea why I am getting this -- any suggestions?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

Q = 60;

A = 4000;

nb = 0.42;

dens = 1.48;

Co = 0.05;

Vx = Q/A;

Dx = 73.51*Vx + 0.282;

R = 1 + (dens/nb)*(0.9292/(1 + 0.092*Ccu[x, t])^2);

reator = Dx*D[Ccu[x, t], x, x] - Vx*D[Ccu[x, t], x] - 
   R*D[Ccu[x, t], t];

initial = Ccu[x, 0] == 0;

b1 = {Ccu[0, t] == Co, Ccu[300000, t] == 0};

regiao = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, 500000}}];

solucao = 
 NDSolve[{reator == 0, initial, 
   DirichletCondition[Ccu[x, t] == Co, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[Ccu[x, t] == 0, x == 100000]}, 
   Ccu, {t, 0, 100000}, {x} ∈ regiao]
```

> CoefficientArrays::poly: -(1+3.27432/(1+0.092 Ccu)^2) Ccu\$11498-(3 Ccu\$11499)/200 + 1.38465 Ccu\$11500 is not a polynomial. >>
>
> NDSolve::femper: PDE parsing error of {-(1+3.27432/(1+0.092 Ccu)^2) Ccu\$11498-(3 Ccu\$11499)/200+1.38465 Ccu\$11500}. Inconsistent equation dimensions. >>

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 10):

A small remark on the error:

> `CoefficientArrays::poly`: `-(1 + 3.27432/(1 + 0.092 Ccu)^2) Ccu11498 - (3 Ccu11499)/200 + 1.38465 Ccu$11500` is not a polynomial. >>

First note that `Ccu` is your *dependent variable* in your PDE.  The expression being complained about has several variables, `Ccu` and ones like `Ccu$11498`..  (The ones like `Ccu$11498` are internal, localized variables representing the derivatives of `Ccu` in the PDE).  Since `Ccu` appears in the denominator, the expression is not a polynomial.  You can call [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html) on the expression to see the identical message.

As [Michael Siefert](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27813/michael-seifert) has pointed out, [FEM handles only linear PDEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html) currently (V10.1).

As I pointed out in [Kernel quits without error in NDSolveValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80274/kernel-quits-without-error-in-ndsolvevalue/80304#80304), this error should be caught internally and the more useful error `NDSolve::femnonlinear` returned in its place.

Answer (score 8):

*Mathematica*'s finite element PDE methods only work for linear PDEs as of v10.1.  See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57033/solving-a-nonlinear-pde-with-mathematica10-fem-solver) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/how-to-solve-a-nonlinear-coupled-pde-with-initial-and-some-boundary-values) for some other tips on how to deal with this.  Given the form of your equation (some kind of non-linear reaction-diffusion equation?), I would suspect that you're better off using Mathematica's default "Method of Lines" algorithm than trying to use finite element methods.