# Differential equations in partial derivatives

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, physics

I am trying to get numeric solution for equations:
$$
\left\{x^{(2,0)}(u,t) \left(1-\frac{y^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2}{\left(x^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2+y^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)+\frac{x^{(1,0)}(u,t) y^{(1,0)}(u,t) y^{(2,0)}(u,t)}{\left(x^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2+y^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2\right)^{3/2}}-x^{(0,2)}(u,t)=0,-\frac{x^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2 y^{(2,0)}(u,t)}{\left(x^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2+y^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{x^{(2,0)}(u,t) x^{(1,0)}(u,t) y^{(1,0)}(u,t)}{\left(x^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2+y^{(1,0)}(u,t)^2\right)^{3/2}}-y^{(0,2)}(u,t)+y^{(2,0)}(u,t)=0\right\}
$$
with boundary conditions:
$x(0,t)=0,x(1,t)=1,y(0,t)=0,y(1,t)=0,x(u,0)=u,y(u,0)=0,x^{(0,1)}(u,10)=0,y^{(0,1)}(u,10)=0$
Wolfram mathematica says:

CoefficientArrays::poly: $-\text{x$\$$4346}+\text{x$\$$4349} \left(1-\frac{\text{y$\$$4347}^2}{\left(\text{x$\$$4348}^2+\text{y$\$$4347}^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)+\frac{\text{x$\$$4348} \text{y$\$$4347} \text{y$\$$4350}}{\left(\text{x$\$$4348}^2+\text{y$\$$4347}^2\right)^{3/2}}$ is not a polynomial.

NDSolve::femper: PDE parsing error of $\left\{-\text{x$\$$4346}+\text{x$\$$4349} \left(1-\frac{\text{y$\$$4347}^2}{\left(\text{x$\$$4348}^2+\text{y$\$$4347}^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)+\frac{\text{x$\$$4348} \text{y$\$$4347} \text{y$\$$4350}}{\left(\text{x$\$$4348}^2+\text{y$\$$4347}^2\right)^{3/2}},\frac{\text{x$\$$4348} \text{x$\$$4349} \text{y$\$$4347}}{\left(\text{x$\$$4348}^2+\langle\langle 6\rangle\rangle ^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\text{y$\$$4350}-\frac{\text{x$\$$4348}^2 \text{y$\$$4350}}{(\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle +\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle )^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\text{y$\$$4351}\right\}$ . Inconsistent equation dimensions.

What am I doing wrong?

Add, code in mathematica:

```
<< VariationalMethods`

L = 1/2 ((D[x[u, t], t]^2 + D[y[u, t], t]^2) - 
    (Sqrt[D[x[u, t], u]^2 + D[y[u, t], u]^2] - 1)^2)

eq = EulerEquations[L, {x[u, t], y[u, t]}, {u, t}]

cond = {x[0, t] == 0, x[1, t] == 1, y[0, t] == 0, y[1, t] == 0}

addcond = {x[u, 0] == u, y[u, 0] == 0, (D[L, D[x[u, t], t]] /. {t -> 10}) == 0, 
    (D[L, D[y[u, t], t]] /. {t -> 10}) == 0}

NDSolve[{eq, cond, addcond}, {x[u, t], y[u, t]}, {u, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Please copy the actual code you used into your question in Mathematica format so that readers can copy and run it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I added actual code.

Comment: Euler's equations usually are solved as an initial value problem. Here, it is posed as a boundary value problem, with positions specified at `t == 0` and velocities at `t == 10`.  Is this intentional?  With both defined at `t == 0`, the code runs fine.

Comment: You are right. I had to solve it as an initial value problem. But why mathematica can not solve a boundary value problem?

Comment: Here is my understanding, which could be wrong.  Boundary value PDEs are best solved by finite element method, but I do not believe that Mathematica's implementation of FEM can handle nonlinear PDEs.  But, the alternative, the Method of Lines, is meant for initial value problems.  Nonetheless, NDSolve should fail gracefully, not with these strange error messages.  So it may be a bug.  Nonetheless, Mathematica probably can solve your problem by the method described in the Introduction [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1699661144).

Comment: Comment continued.  You would need to decompose your PDEs into a family of coupled ODEs in `t` and then apply the time-related boundary conditions using the "Shooting" `Method`.  I have done this sort of thing, but it takes some work.

Comment: I should add that, because the PDEs are nonlinear, there may be no solution for the given boundary conditions.  Do you have information to the contrary?

Comment: ** Do you have information to the contrary?** - No.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87723/fem-giving-is-not-a-polynomial-error